# JSON.parse failing without reason

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I am using NodeJS, and the following JSON.parse is failing but I cant work out why:

```
> s[0]
'﻿[["hands[0].session.buyin", "332"]]'
> JSON.parse(s[0]);
SyntaxError: Unexpected token ﻿
    at Object.parse (native)
    at repl:1:6
    at REPLServer.self.eval (repl.js:110:21)
    at repl.js:249:20
    at REPLServer.self.eval (repl.js:122:7)
    at Interface.<anonymous> (repl.js:239:12)
    at Interface.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:95:17)
    at Interface._onLine (readline.js:202:10)
    at Interface._line (readline.js:531:8)
    at
```

The string in question has been loaded from a file.  If I copy past the string into the console it works, so my suspicion is that it might be to do with the way the file is encoded, but I just cant work out what.  JSON.parse's error messages are distinctly unhelpful.

Comment: that doesn't look like JSON.

Comment: You could try a JSON Lint service to make sure your JSON is valid.

Comment: `s[0]` looks like two-dimensional array, isn't it?

Comment: What does the line look like in the file? Can you paste the contents?

Comment: `JSON.parse('[["hands[0].session.buyin", "332"]]')` works as expected.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It seem that the `String` includes a [Byte-Order Mark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark).

```
> s[0].charCodeAt(0).toString(16)
'feff'
```

You'll have to [strip that](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim) out before `JSON.parse()` can manage the rest.

```
> JSON.parse(s[0].trim())
[ [ 'hands[0].session.buyin', '332' ] ]
```

Comment: This precisely is the problem.

Answer (score 1):

On Node v0.10.12's REPL, this works fine:

```
> var b = '[["hands[0].session.buyin", "332"]]';
undefined
> JSON.parse(b)
[ [ 'hands[0].session.buyin', '332' ] ]
>
```

The string is a valid JSON representation of a 2D array.

What's your environment?